# Can a control source be plain text?

Tags: ms-access

I need the control source for a textbox to simply be `"x"`.

I have a bunch of textboxes on a report and I need each text box to just have an `x` in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the Control Source property for the TextBox to be:

="x"

This will cause the text box to display an x in the report. However, its contents will not be editable as would be the case with a text box in a form.